# How to prevent access to asset folder (and redirect to other page)?

Tags: assets, url, redirection

I have an asset source with url "/guides/".
When I put a file to this folder, a file gets an url:
domain.com/guides/myfile.pdf

If I go to "domain.com/guides", it shows me the file directory. 
I prevent access to this by creating .htaccess file and now I see a Forbidden page (You don't have permission to access /guides/ on this server).

I have a Guides entry page: domain.com/guides/my-guides-main-page
Is it possible to make a redirection like this:
domain.com/guides -> domain.com/guides/my-guides-main-page

Answer (score 1):

It would be much safer and easier to work with if you put all assets folders into domain.com/assets/ as it can cause such conflicts.